# Trying to learn how to use python random.choice()

Tags: python, random

I am incredibly new to programming so please bear with me. I tried searching for the answer to my question with previous posts but had no luck there. My issue is that I am reading a beginner book for python and in it they give an example of how to use random.choice for python 2.7. This example is as follows;

```
import random

t = [1, 2, 3]
random.choice(t)
```

the book then shows a result from 1 to 3. This didn't work for me and I even tried putting;

```
print t
```

but all I get is `[1, 2, 3,]` printed as a result.

Thank you for any help you can give me and sorry I am so new at this! If I am posting in the wrong place feel free to point me in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: `print random.choice(t)`

Comment: this book assumes that you're using the interactive console, where all functions not returning `None` print their results.

Comment: `print t` will only output the list you have created, you need to assign the result to something and then print it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help everyone! Your replies helped a great deal and I now understand what is going on. I am new to this forum and there doesn't seem to be an upvote or else I would do so for each of you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the result to a variable for further processing steps:

```
choice = random.choice(t)
print(choice)
```